# NAT64 return translation doesn't work

Tags: cisco, ipv4, ipv6

I'm doing a NAT64 translation on cisco router. The translation from IPv6 to IPv4 work but the return isn't translated neighter in the NAT64 statistics.

```
config:

 interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 nat64 enable
 ipv6 address 2001:2525:3164:1000::1/64


interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0
 ip address 194.10.83.2 255.255.255.248
 nat64 enable

nat64 v4 pool pool1 194.10.83.2 194.10.83.2
nat64 v6v4 list nat64ACL pool pool1 overload

ipv6 access-list nat64ACL
 permit ipv6 2001:2525:3164:1000::/56 any
```

Translation table:

```
RM_A0.1#sh nat64 translations
Proto   Original IPv4           Translated IPv4
        Translated IPv6         Original IPv6
--------------------------------------------------------
icmp    194.10.83.1:1           [64:FF9B::C20A:5301]:1
        194.10.83.2:1           [2001:2525:3164:1000:6188:82D:86F8:708E]:1

tcp     194.10.83.1:23          [64:FF9B::C20A:5301]:23
        194.10.83.2:60531       [2001:2525:3164:1000:6188:82D:86F8:708E]:60531

Total number of translations: 2
```

statistics:

```
Number of packets translated by stateless NAT64:
        Packets translated (IPv4 -> IPv6): 0
        Packets translated (IPv6 -> IPv4): 0

Number of packets translated by stateful NAT64:
        Packets translated (IPv4 -> IPv6): 0
        Packets translated (IPv6 -> IPv4): 75

Global Statistics
Prefix: 64:FF9B::/96
        Packets translated (IPv4 -> IPv6): 0
        Packets translated (IPv6 -> IPv4): 20
        Packets dropped: 0
```

Wireshark capture on ipv4 network:
[image]

on the IPv4 network everything looks fine. Any idea?

edit:
that's the whole configuration of the router:

```
Current configuration : 2039 bytes
!
version 15.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname RM_A0.1
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
enable password emf
!
no aaa new-model
memory-size iomem 15
!
ip cef
ipv6 unicast-routing
ipv6 dhcp pool myPool
 dns-server 2001:4860:4860::8888
 domain-name Baldi.local
!
ipv6 cef
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
cts logging verbose
!
license udi pid CISCO1921/K9 sn FCZ1918C2N2
!
vtp domain emf
vtp mode transparent
vtp version 2
!
redundancy
!
interface Embedded-Service-Engine0/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 ipv6 address FE80::1:1:0 link-local
 ipv6 address 2001:2525:3164:100F::/127
 ipv6 ospf 99 area 0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 nat64 enable
 ipv6 address FE80::1:1:1 link-local
 ipv6 address 2001:2525:3164:1000::1/64
 ipv6 nd other-config-flag
 ipv6 dhcp server myPool
 ipv6 ospf 99 area 0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0
 ip address 194.10.83.2 255.255.255.248
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 nat64 enable
!
interface Serial0/1/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 clock rate 2000000
!
interface Serial0/1/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 clock rate 2000000
!
router ospfv3 99
 router-id 0.0.0.1
 !
 address-family ipv6 unicast
 exit-address-family
!
router rip
 version 2
 network 194.10.83.0
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
!
nat64 v4 pool pool1 194.10.83.2 194.10.83.2
nat64 v6v4 list nat64ACL pool pool1 overload
!
ipv6 access-list nat64ACL
 permit ipv6 2001:2525:3164:1000::/56 any
!
control-plane
!
line con 0
line aux 0
line 2
 no activation-character
 no exec
 transport preferred none
 transport output pad telnet rlogin lapb-ta mop udptn v120 ssh
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 password emf
 login
 transport input none
!
scheduler allocate 20000 1000
ntp server 2001:2525:3164:1F::
!
end
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you are receiving any return traffic to the NAT table because there are no drops. You should edit your question to include the entire router configuration. There are other configurations that may be part of the problem.

Comment: Okey I added my configuration

Comment: Try and add an access list for returning IPv4 traffic and see if it reaches your interface first.

Comment: I added a access list but there are indeed matches...
I added: permit ip any any on inbound IPv4 interface

Comment: You seem to be missing a couple of commands: `nat64 prefix stateful ipv6-prefix/length` and `nat64 v6v4 static ipv6-address ipv4-address`. Cisco has documentation on how to configure NAT64

Comment: the first command is in my opinion if you want another prefix as 64:9ffb:: ... the second one is for a static NAT 1to1. I'm doing a nat64 dynamic NAT (overload)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okey I found the solution:
the v4 pool can't be in the same subnet as the interface is.
with an IP in another subnet everything works fine